# android custom IME keyboard service

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, ime

what is the keycode for next button to move to next edittext in listview item? currently my next button is equivalent to enter button keycode. I base my xml on this tutorial site: https://android.jlelse.eu/learn-to-create-a-system-keyboard-on-android-95aca21b1e5f

below is the current xml keyboard layout:

```
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:keyWidth="20%p"
    android:horizontalGap="0dp"
    android:verticalGap="0dp"
    android:keyHeight="60dp">

    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="49" android:keyLabel="1" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
        <Key android:codes="50" android:keyLabel="2"/>
        <Key android:codes="51" android:keyLabel="3"/>
        <Key android:codes="-5"
            android:keyIcon="@drawable/backspace"
            android:keyWidth="40%p"
            android:keyEdgeFlags="right"
            android:isRepeatable="true"/>
    </Row>

    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="52" android:keyLabel="4" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
        <Key android:codes="53" android:keyLabel="5" />
        <Key android:codes="54" android:keyLabel="6" android:keyEdgeFlags="right" />
    </Row>

    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="55" android:keyLabel="7" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
        <Key android:codes="56" android:keyLabel="8"/>
        <Key android:codes="57" android:keyLabel="9" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
    </Row>

    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="48" android:keyLabel="0" android:keyEdgeFlags="left" />
        <Key android:codes="46" android:keyLabel="."  />
        <Key android:codes="10"
            android:keyLabel="NEXT"
            android:keyWidth="60%p"
            android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
    </Row>

</Keyboard>
```

Comment: What you want exactly I mean when you type something in edit text and after that you want to move next edittext when click on next button of keyboard am I right...??? Or something else you want.

Comment: yes, in a list view item with 1 edittext per item, using the built in IME softkeyboard input type numeric when click next button can move to next item edittext, but on custom IME i don't know how to implement the next button feature as i don't know the keycode for the next button or if you should programmatically move to next item edittext

Comment: Have you tried this in xml android:imeOptions="actionNext"

Comment: just added, not work, since the custom IME keyboard's keycode is of ENTER which is 10, but I dont know the keycode for NEXT button function

Comment: Try using `keycode` `KEYCODE_TAB`. and its value is `61` . [here is referance https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_TAB](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_TAB)

Comment: 61 value is equivalent to the character '=' when used on android